# Is it possible to use geom_text to put text below each facet panel and align it with the tick marks?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have added text lines (ind = 305, ind = 182...) on the facet_wrap plot of bellow. I am looking for a way to get these text lines just beneath the tick marks in each facet panel. I have searched and tried many options that include the phrase "put text outside the ploting area" but I wasn't able to solve my problem.

[image]

This is the code I used to generate the plot. Any feasible option?

```
ggplot(df1, aes(Sex, value)) +    
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Sex), alpha = 0.2) + 
  theme_bw() +    
  facet_wrap(.~trait.code, nrow = 2, scales = "free") +    
  geom_text(data = df2[df2$Sex == "Female",], aes(label = ind), size = 4, fontface="bold") +    
  geom_text(data = df2[df2$Sex == "Male",], aes(label = ind), size = 4, fontface="bold") +  
  theme(axis.title.x= element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        legend.position="bottom", 
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
        panel.spacing.y = unit(2, "lines")) + 
  ggtitle("Any tittle")
```

Here is a subset of the data

> ```r
> df1 <- structure(list(Sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
> 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L,
> 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 1L,
> 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L,
> 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
> 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", "Male" ), class = "factor"),
> value = c(80L, 108L, 48L, 89L, 80L, 62L,  96L, 143L, 108L, 94L, 201L,
> 171L, 211L, 117L, 195L, 149L, 130L,  100L, 206L, 150L, 10L, 8L, 10L,
> 6L, 8L, 16L, 32L, 16L, 19L, 22L,  40L, 30L, 50L, 22L, 41L, 15L, 22L,
> 16L, 42L, 20L, 13L, 23L, 18L,  19L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 30L, 23L, 20L, 30L,
> 25L, 26L, 26L, 28L, 27L,  25L, 22L, 23L, 19L, 1L, 50L, 35L, 121L, 16L,
> 10L, 166L, 376L,  153L, 228L, 224L, 93L, 498L, 140L, 108L, 286L, 371L,
> 312L, 104L,  353L), trait.code = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
> 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
> 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
> 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,  3L,
> 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L,
> 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Tra1", "Tra2", "Tra3",  "Tra4"),
> class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
> -80L))
>
> df2 <- structure(
>   list(
>     trait.code = structure(
>       c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L),
>       .Label = c("Tra1", "Tra2", "Tra3", "Tra4"),
>       class = "factor"
>     ),
>     Sex = c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male",
>             "Female", "Male", "Female"),
>     value = c(44.5, 44.5, 6.6, 6.6, 7.24, 7.24, 72.9, 72.9),
>     trait.order3 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L),
>     ind = structure(
>       c(1L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L),
>       .Label = c("ind=\n 182", "ind=\n 190", "ind=\n 195",
>                  "ind=\n 200", "ind=\n 202", "ind=\n 305",
>                  "ind=\n 309", "ind=\n 348"),
>       class = "factor"
>     )
>   ),
>   class = "data.frame",
>   row.names = c(NA, 8L)
> )
> ```

Comment: Instead of using `geom_text`, you should be looking at modifying the labels of the x-axes.

Comment: @csgroen Any suggestion how to replace the original labels (Female and Male) by the text lines I have added by using geom_text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick here was to use the `ind` variable as your x-axis aesthetic. For this, I propose using a join with your metadata `df2` and your original `df1`, which contains the observations. To join them, I 'combined' the `trait.code` and `Sex` and used a `left_join`.

```
#-- Add 'trait.comb' for join
df2 <- df2 %>%
    mutate(ind = str_remove(ind, "\n "),
           trait.comb = paste(trait.code, Sex, sep = "~")) %>%
    select(trait.comb, ind

#-- Add the information in df2 to df1 by joining using trait.comb
df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(trait.comb = paste(trait.code, Sex, sep = "~")) %>%
    left_join(df2, by = "trait.comb") %>%
    select(-trait.comb)

#-- Plot using the ind as your x-axis aesthetic
ggplot(df1, aes(ind, value)) +    
    facet_wrap(.~trait.code, nrow = 2, scales = "free") +    
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Sex), alpha = 0.2) + 
    theme_bw() +    
    theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
          legend.position="bottom", 
          panel.spacing.y = unit(2, "lines")) + 
    ggtitle("Any title")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 3):

To answer the original question: `geom_text()` can draw outside the plot panel if you turn off clipping with `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")`.

```r
ggplot(df1, aes(Sex, value)) +    
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Sex), alpha = 0.2) + 
  theme_bw() +    
  facet_wrap(.~trait.code, nrow = 2, scales = "free") +    
  geom_text(
    data = df2[df2$Sex == "Female",],
    aes(label = ind, y = -Inf), size = 4, vjust = 1.2, fontface="bold"
  ) +    
  geom_text(
    data = df2[df2$Sex == "Male",],
    aes(label = ind, y = -Inf), size = 4, vjust = 1.2, fontface="bold"
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(axis.title.x= element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        legend.position="bottom",
        legend.box.spacing = unit(2, "lines"),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
        panel.spacing.y = unit(2.5, "lines")) + 
  ggtitle("Any tittle")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>